complete a variable from inside a function with both dynamic variable name and completition range
I want to create a function that completes a variable with a given range, both passed to the function as an argument.
# The sample data frame. The colum g1 normaly has the range 1 to 5, but in this
# filtered subset it only has the range 2 to 5:  
z <- data.frame(gender = c('f','f','f','f'), g1 = c(2,3,4,5), n = c(3,2,8,3))


# The function:
test <- function(data, variable, range) {  
    # thats what i actually want to do
    #tmp <- data %>% complete(g1 = 1:5)
    # and thats my not working attempt
    tmp <- data %>% complete("{{variable}}" = range)
    
    return(tmp)
}

# And the way I want to call the function:  
z %>% test(g1, 1:5)

this produces the result i want, but without my function
z %>% complete(gender, g1 = 1:5, fill = list(n = 0))

  gender    g1     n
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 f          1     0
2 f          2     3
3 f          3     2
4 f          4     8
5 f          5     3

It`s probably better to convert g1 to a factor, but i would really like to know how to do it without a factor.

library(tidyr)
test <- function(data, variable, range, fill) {  
  
  # no quotes around {{ variable }}
  # use :=
  tmp <- data %>% complete({{ variable }} := range, fill = fill)
  
  return(tmp)
}

# And the way I want to call the function:  
z %>% test(g1, 1:5, fill = list(n = 0, gender = 'f'))

# A tibble: 5 × 3
     g1 gender     n
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
1     1 f          0
2     2 f          3
3     3 f          2
4     4 f          8
5     5 f          3

tidyeval is definitely weird to get used to, but it starts to make sense with practice.
You can find a tidyeval cheatsheet (PDF) from here

Great answer I've tried it with double-curly-brackets as i've used that before, but with a single equals sign instead of colon-equals. Thanks for the cheat-sheet link! Also a good idea to move the fill parameter from complete into the function argument list :)
